# Run Command-Failed! Error in compiling Ionic Project

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

> npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-angular@latest
>   ✖ Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-angular@latest (exit code 1):

```
    npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-plugin-angular@latest

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/miracle/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T13_48_39_761Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

try `npm i ionic-angular --save`. I think it must w
ork , you can try this

Comment: npm i ionic-angular --save try this